# Trying to update a simple Gauge control

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My brief is a (relatively) simple on: receive numeric values from an open WebSocket, and update a gauge with the numbers as they're received.

I have everything **apart** from the ability to load the new number into the store, and have the gauge respond.

Longer term I should like to write my own Proxy to interact with the websocket connection, but as an aid to understanding Ext.JS I should like to do this manually.

Can anyone recommend a resource were a manually edited value is directly reflected in an Ext.JS chart?

Your clues are most welcome,

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store.getAt(0).record.set('myGaugeVal', 10)`

Trying to disassociate the chart from a store just sounds like it will bring pain. Just manually over-ride the value in the store itself